# How to make generics in collection type constraint?

Tags: ios, swift, generics, option-type

I have been trying to extract non-nil values from the String array. Like below. But, my senior wants it to be able to extract **non-nil values** from other types too.

I read, **generics** could help me for handling different types. How can I use generics so that I get to use following like extension to work with other types too?

`getNonNil` must return the extracted non-nil values of the specific type (i.e. **if array is [String?] it must return [String], returns [Int] if [Int?]**)

Because I have to do further calculations.

What I have tried is below:

```
import Foundation
// Extended the collection-type so that collectiontype is constrained to having element with optional strings
extension CollectionType where Self.Generator.Element == Optional<String>{
    func getNonNil() -> [String] {
        // filter out all nil elements and forcefully unwrap them using map
        return self.filter({$0 != nil}).map({$0!})
    }
}

// Usage
let x: [String?] = ["Er", "Err", nil, "errr"]

x.getNonNil().forEach { (str) in
    print(str)
}
```

Answer (score 4):

For `getNonNil` you could simply use

```
x.flatMap { $0 }
// returns ["Er", "Err", "errr"] which is [String]
```

---

For the original question, typically you could introduce a protocol to the Optional type (e.g. via the [muukii/OptionalProtocol](https://github.com/muukii/OptionalProtocol) package):

```
protocol OptionalProtocol {
    associatedtype Wrapped
    var value: Wrapped? { get }
}

extension Optional: OptionalProtocol {
    public var value: Wrapped? { return self }
}

extension CollectionType where Self.Generator.Element: OptionalProtocol {
    func getNonNil() -> [Self.Generator.Element.Wrapped] {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: flatmap worked. But in 2nd solution, How can i use it? Can you show me a example? Because, when I tried I got "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value" or other error.

Comment: @Dari You would want to do `return flatMap {$0.value}` in the `getNonNil` method.

Answer (score 2):

There's no easy way of achieving this through an extension, as you cannot introduce new generic types into extensions (although this is [part of the Swift Generics Manifesto](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/docs/GenericsManifesto.md#parameterized-extensions) – so may well be possibly in a future version of Swift).

As [@kennytm says](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38434505/2976878), the simplest solution is just to use `flatMap`, which filters out `nil`:

```
x.flatMap{$0}.forEach { (str) in
    print(str)
}
```

If however, you still want this as an extension, you *could* use a protocol workaround in order to allow you to constrain the extension to any optional element type (Swift 3):

```
protocol _OptionalProtocol {
    associatedtype Wrapped
    func _asOptional() -> Wrapped?
}

extension Optional : _OptionalProtocol {
    func _asOptional() -> Wrapped? {return self}
}

extension Collection where Self.Iterator.Element : _OptionalProtocol {
    func getNonNil() -> [Iterator.Element.Wrapped] {
        return flatMap{$0._asOptional()}
    }
} 

...

let x : [String?] = ["Er", "Err", nil, "errr"]

x.getNonNil().forEach { (str) in
    print(str)
}
```

<sup>(In Swift 3, `CollectionType` has been renamed to `Collection`, and `Generator` is now `Iterator`)</sup>

Although `flatMap` is almost certainly preferred in this situation, I'm only really adding this for the sake of completion.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest approach is using `flatMap` as **kennytm** suggested, but if you absolutely want to know how to create such a method using generics, one approach would be to create a global method that takes in the collection as a parameter:

```
public func getNonNil<T, C: CollectionType where C.Generator.Element == Optional<T>>(collection: C) -> [T] {
    return collection.filter({$0 != nil}).map({$0!})
}

let x: [String?] = ["Er", "Err", nil, "errr"]

print(getNonNil(x)) // returns ["Er", "Err", "errr"]
```