# Why does flatMap used via an extension return different results than when called directly?

Tags: arrays, swift, sequence, flatmap

Consider this code...

```
import Foundation

let source = ["A", "B", nil, "D"]
print(type(of:source))

let result1 = source.flatMap{ $0 }
print(type(of:result1))
print(result1)

extension Array
{
    func sameThing() -> Array
    {
        return self.flatMap{ $0 }
    }
}

let result2 = source.sameThing()
print(type(of:result2))
print(result2)
```

`result1` is an `Array<String>` while `result2` is an `Array<Optional<String>>`.  But why?

I've tried using a Sequence instead of an array, but no luck there either.

Comment: That still doesn't explain the `nil` in `result2`

Comment: For a way to make this work for Optional arrays, see http://stackoverflow.com/q/38434125/2976878

Answer (score 1):

Your return type preserves generic type

```
func sameThing(separator:String = " ") -> Array
```

Therefore on optional elements signature of this operation is equivalent to `[T?] -> [T?]`

`Sequence.flatMap` has two overloads with specifically crafted signatures

```
func flatMap<SegmentOfResult : Sequence>(
    _ transform: (${GElement}) throws -> SegmentOfResult
) rethrows -> [SegmentOfResult.${GElement}]

func flatMap<ElementOfResult>(
    _ transform: (${GElement}) throws -> ElementOfResult?
) rethrows -> [ElementOfResult] {
```

The second one wins. But since you asked for array of optionals, `ElementOfResult` becomes `Optional<String>`, and `transform` becomes `Optional<String> -> Optional<Optional<String>>`.

Thus when closure `{ $0 }` returns `nil`, it gets lifted to `Optional(nil)`, i.e. having `.some(nil)` value, not `.none`. Then it will pass the nil guard and appear in result.

Comment: Interesting!  I keep forgetting how Swift uses return types as part of the signature which other languages like C# do not.  That said, how would I modify my function to exactly match what flatMap returns?  I'm trying to encapsulate some functionality--of which flatMap is part of--so I can reuse it. Kinda stumped there.