# Protocol extension with Optional AssociatedType

Tags: swift, generics, swift-protocols

I want to extend the protocol with associated type `Optional<Something>`. In other words: I want to extend concrete generic type `SomeType` which will have declaration:

```
var a: SomeType<Optional<Something>>
```

but to not extend following type:

```
var b: SomeType<Something>
```

Here is the more elaborate example of what I want to achieve.
Obviously this example is wrong. Using `Any` is especially wrong, but I hope the example will highlight the intention:

```
var thisSequenceIWantToExtend: [Optional<String>] = []
var alsoWantToExtend: [Optional<Int>] = []
var dontWantToExtend: [Int] = []


extension Sequence where Iterator.Element == Optional<Any>
{
    func somethingWithOptionalSequence(){
        print("XXX")
    }
}

//these should work
thisSequenceIWantToExtend.somethingWithOptionalSequence()
alsoWantToExtend.somethingWithOptionalSequence()

//this shouldn't be extended
//dontWantToExtend.somethingWithOptionalSequence()
```

**Answer** (Swift3):

```
protocol OptionalProtocol {
    associatedtype Wrapped
    var value: Wrapped? { get }
}

extension Optional: OptionalProtocol {
    public var value: Wrapped? { return self }

}

extension Collection where Self.Iterator.Element: OptionalProtocol {
    func nonNil()->[Iterator.Element.Wrapped] {
        return self.flatMap{ $0.value }
    }
}


var a: [Optional<String>] = ["a",nil,"B"]
var b: [Optional<Int>] = [1,2,3]
var c: [Int] = [1,2,3]

a.nonNil()
b.nonNil()

// can't do that
//c.nonNil()
```

Comment: Compare [How to make generics in collection type constraint?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38434125/2976878) – you can use a 'dummy protocol'.

Comment: Thank you. This is the answer I was looking for. However, it might be useful to post the example which is updated to Swift 3

Comment: I've actually just undeleted my answer that was on the linked Q&A, which shows a Swift 3 example :)

Comment: @Hamish great, your answer is fully satisfying:)