# Swift generics to detect optional associated type

Tags: swift, generics

How would I restrict an extension to only match when an associated type is optional?

For example:

```swift
protocol FooProtocol: class {
    associatedtype BarType
    var contents: BarType { get }
}

extension FooProtocol where BarType: Optional<Any> {
    func unwrap() -> BarType {
        return self.contents!
    }
}

class BazClass: FooProtocol {
    typealias BarType = String?
    var contents: BarType
}
```

This errors with `Type 'Self.BarType' constrained to non-protocol type 'Optional<Any>'` on the opening brace of the extension. I've also tried `Any?`, `BarType?` in place of `Optional<Any>`. The last one errors with `Inheritance from non-named type 'BarType?'` in stead.

Comment: Compare [How to make generics in collection type constraint?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38434125/2976878). Swift doesn't support parameterized extensions yet, so one solution would be to define a protocol.

Comment: Note that your `unwrap()` method returns the wrong type. Even in your desired syntax, you mean `unwrap()` to return `BarType.Wrapped`. But you can't use this to get to the kind of generic solution you're looking for. Swift doesn't have higher kinded types; you can't talk about all "Optionals." You have to type-parameterize it to something. I would back up a bit and look at the underlying problem (please tell it isn't JSON parsing; it's always JSON parsing when someone wants advanced type features…) and head in a different direction. Trying to make Optionals "special" is a deep pit of madness.

Comment: (Basically, what are you actually going to do with `.unwrap()` that is materially better than `x.contents!`? Why put an optional in `FooProtocol` rather than just making the variable holding `FooProtocol` itself optional?)

Comment: @RobNapier I've reimplemented reactivex.io because I'm an idiot, apparently :) - Event Consumers should be able to handle 'it went away' (eg: a profile icon view, resetting to blank on receiving nil). However a bunch of calls return streams or nil eg: `EventStream<User>?` which Swift rejects trying to assign a consumer eg: `EventStream<User?>?`. So I wanted some concise way of expressing "unwrap and make the contents optional if the inner-stream is optional" for a stream that emits another, optional, stream. That is: `EventStream<EventStream<User>?>` -> to -> `EventStream<User?>`

Comment: First, I highly recommend looking at the existing solutions: RxSwift and ReactiveSwift (or just build a much simpler Rx framework from scratch, but *much* simpler; like a few hundred lines of code at most). But to your point, why is this `EventStream<EventStream<User>?> -> EventStream<User?>` rather than `EventStream<EventStream<User>?> -> EventStream<User>?`? I believe you're breaking the monadic rules in your version of `sequence` (a la Haskell)

Comment: Mine CLOCs at 474 ATM; I could prune a lot of that though. I couldn't get my head around them :( I'm looking for `ES<ES<U>?> -> ES<U?>` because 'user emitter went away' is the same as 'no user found' as far as a profile icon is concerned. Allowing `ES<U>?` means the 'clear previous icon' action has to be handled separately, including building a new chain of streams and subscribing to that, in stead of just firing nil into the existing, pre-built chain of streams. The stream contents could look like `OAuthClient->FetchMyself->User->ProfileIconURL->UIImage` for this example.

Comment: @Hamish The link in your comment fixed my problem; would you like to post it as an answer?

Comment: @ReactiveRaven Might as well just close as a dupe – the solution is exactly the same.

Answer (score 2):

String and Optional are value types, not protocols. That's why you cannot say `BarType: Optional<String>`, because there is nothing which can inherit from that.

You can use a same type constraint <s>(but this is only possible in Swift 4)</s> Seems to work in Swift 3.1 aswell:

```
extension FooProtocol where BarType == String? {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: `where BarType == String?` or `where BarType is String?` ?

Comment: `where BarType == String?`

Comment: Thanks for the explanation; I should probably have placeholder'd `String` too though; there are a wide variety of types passing through not just one unfortunately :(